# Magento 2 Show Text with Shipping Option

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, shipping-methods

I have created a shipping option and wanted text to show if that option was selected. Right now it displays when the shipping method is selected but below all of the shipping options.  I want it to display with the method (not below all of them) if that method is selected.

[image]

frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="shipping-info-wrapper" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">My_Module/js/view/customjs</item>
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

js/view/customjs

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'

], function (Component, ko, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Matt6_PickUp/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            var self = this._super();
            this.showFreeShippingInfo = ko.computed(function() {
                var method = quote.shippingMethod();

                if(method && method['carrier_code'] !== undefined) {
                    if(method['carrier_code'] === 'freeshipping') {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;

            }, this);

            this.showPickUpShippingInfo = ko.computed(function() {
                var method = quote.shippingMethod();

                if(method && method['carrier_code'] !== undefined) {
                    if(method['carrier_code'] === 'instorepickup') {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;

            }, this);

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

web/template/customtemp.html

```
<div class="free-shipping-info" data-bind="visible: showFreeShippingInfo()" style="display: none;">
<div class="step-title" data-role="title" data-bind="i18n: 'Free Shipping Information'"></div>
<p class="desc" data-bind="i18n: 'Free shipping can take up to 2 weeks.'"></p>
```

How can I show the info with the option when it is selected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html

```
<tr class="row row-error"
    if="method.error_message">
    <td class="col col-error" colspan="4">
        <div role="alert" class="message error">
            <div text="method.error_message"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="no-display">
            <input type="radio"
                   attr="'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code" />
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

change your message like you add your custom message as

```
    <tr class="row" if="method.shipping_info">
         <td class="col" colspan="4">
            <!--your message here -->
         </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I will give that a try.  I don't need to change anything in checkout_index_index.xml or my JS file?

Comment: That by itself did not work.  It just breaks.  There must be more to do with checkout_index_index.xml and the JS file.